# How to assign values one by one from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an array of objects `this.selection.selected` which can have one or more values.

The below code is working fine if the array has only one value.

```
0: {hostName: "abc123"}
length: 1


console.log(this.selection.selected);
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(saDialogComp, {
    width: '600px'
    data: {
        hostName: this.selection.selected[0].hostName
    }
});
```

How to make it work if the array has multiple objects as below?

```
0: {hostName: "abc123"}
1: {hostName: "abc456"}
length: 2
```

Comment: Please provide the desired value of `hostName` to be outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `this.selection.selected` is an array, you can map a function over it to get all of the hostnames from the objects.

Depending on what your `this.dialog.open` needs to accept as the second parameter, you can try to modify your data to something like this:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(saDialogComp, {
    width: '600px',
    data: {
        hostNames: this.selection.selected.map(a => a.hostName)
    }
});
```

hostNames will now be an array of values from those objects, like:

```
[ 'abc123', 'abc456' ]
```

This will work with any amount of values in the array, be it one or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend `data.hostName` to be a string, then you can:

```js
// ...
data: {
  hostName: this.selection.selected.map(o => o.hostName).join(', ')
}
```

This will:

1. convert the array of objects to an array of strings (only the value of the name);
2. join those strings into a single comma-separated string